# Java: implement long type overflow immunity with assert

Tags: java, jvm, assert, assertions

Here is my code to calculate different operations on rational numbers. Now, my task is to implement additional security with `assert` to protect it from overflow. I tried to do something, but when I enabled assertion with `-ea` to JVM, it started to "throw" assertion all the time (even with `4 > 5` assert condition). **How I can implement this and what is the proper way of doing it on** `Long` **numbers ?**

```
public class Rational {

private final long numerator;
private final long denominator;
private double result;

public Rational(long numerator, long denominator){
    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
    result = (double)numerator/(double)denominator;
}

public Rational plus(Rational b){
    assert this.denominator * b.denominator >= Long.MAX_VALUE : "Overflow of denominator in 'PLUS'"; //My attempt

    long plusDenominator = this.denominator * b.denominator;
    long plusNumerator = ((plusDenominator / this.denominator) * this.numerator) + ((plusDenominator / b.denominator) * b.numerator);
    long gcd = gcd(plusNumerator, plusDenominator);
    return new Rational(plusNumerator / gcd, plusDenominator / gcd);
}

public Rational minus(Rational b){
    long minusDenominator = this.denominator * b.denominator;
    long minusNumerator = ((minusDenominator / this.denominator) * this.numerator) - ((minusDenominator / b.denominator) * b.numerator);
    long gcd = gcd(minusNumerator, minusDenominator);
    return new Rational(minusNumerator / gcd, minusDenominator / gcd);
}

public Rational times(Rational b){
    long timesDenominator = this.denominator * b.denominator;
    long timesNumerator = this.numerator * b.numerator;

    long gcd = gcd(timesDenominator, timesNumerator);
    return new Rational(timesNumerator / gcd, timesDenominator / gcd);
}

public Rational divides(Rational b){
    long divDenominator = this.denominator * b.numerator;
    long divNumerator = this.numerator * b.denominator;

    long gcd = gcd(divNumerator, divDenominator);
    return new Rational(divNumerator / gcd, divDenominator / gcd);
}

private long gcd(long p, long q){
    if(q == 0) return p;
    long r = p % q;
    return gcd(q, r);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Rational r1 = new Rational(8, 999999999999999999L);
    Rational r2 = new Rational(8 ,999999999999999999L);
    System.out.println(r1.plus(r2));
}
```

}

Comment: `even with 4 > 5 condition`. `assert condition` means that you expect `condition` to be true, and that the program must end if `condition` is `false` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html). No surprise that `4 > 5` fires it.

Comment: If third-party libraries are fair game, Guava's [`LongMath.checkedMultiply`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#checkedMultiply(long,%20long)) is an optimized multiply-and-check-for-overflow method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests like the following:

```
assert this.denominator * b.denominator >= Long.MAX_VALUE . . .
```

can't be right. if `this.denominator * b.denominator` overflows, the result will likely be negative; it certainly cannot be larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` and stands little chance of being equal to `Long.MAX_VALUE`. You need a more effective way of detecting that overflow will occur.

The usual way to do this is to either upcast to a larger integer size or to do pretesting. Since you are using `long` already, the only upcast available would be to `BigInteger`, which I assume you don't want to use. Here's how you might use pretesting:

```
static final long safeMultiply(long left, long right)
                 throws ArithmeticException {
  if (right > 0
         ? left > Long.MAX_VALUE/right || left < Long.MIN_VALUE/right 
         : (right < -1
             ? left > Long.MIN_VALUE/right  || left < Long.MAX_VALUE/right
             : right == -1 && left == Long.MIN_VALUE) ) {
      throw new ArithmeticException("Long overflow");
  }
  return left * right;
}
```

I don't recommend using `assert` at all for this, because it can be turned off at run time. You could maintain a flag somewhere whether to signal overflow and skip the testing if it is `false`.